# AngularJS passing data from a directive controller to another

Tags: angularjs

I have a form, which with you can edit an image gallery, of course I've created a directive for it, like this:

galleryEdit.html

```
<div>
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <label>Headline:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="gallery.headline" placeholder="Enter headline here" value=""/>

    <label>channels:</label>
    <channelselect></channelselect>

    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

So, galleryEdit has another directive channelSelect, which with you can select a channel (not only for galleries)

channelselect.html

```
<div>
  <select>
      <option value="{{channel.shortCode}}">{{channel.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

GalleryEdit has a controller, that passes data (called "gallery") for its directive, so its $scope has $scope.gallery property, which contains channel id: $scope.gallery.channel. 
Since channelselect has different controller, that has its scope, this gallery.channel cannot be seen from that scope. 
Is there any way to pass data from gallery to channel controller/directive ?
Using $scope.$parent is not a solution, since channelSelect should not know anything where the data is coming from.

Comment: Just because both directives have a controller does not mean that they have separate scopes.  The `scope` attribute on the directive definition object determines if a new scope (or not) is created, and whether a new scope is an isolate scope or not.  So one possible solution is to not create any new scopes, then both directives would share the same scope, and hence have access to all the same $scope properties/data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up bi-directional binding between your `galleryEdit` directive's scope and your `channelselect` directive's scope.

In your `channelselect` directive's definition, you can do something like the following:

```
directive('channelselect', [function () {
    ...
    scope: {channel: '='}
    ...
}])
```

This will create an **isolated scope** for your `channelselect` directive, and will let you use the `channel` attribute on your `<channelselect>` tag to set up a **bi-directional binding** to its parent scope.

So now you can do this in `galleryEdit.html`:

```
<channelselect channel="gallery.channel"></channelselect>
```

Now `channelselect`'s `$scope.channel` will be bound to `galleryEdit`'s `$scope.gallery.channel`.

See the **Directive Definition Object** section of AngularJS's [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) guide for more details on isolated scopes.